# Using functions with PIVOT in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g, pivot, aggregate-functions

I am trying to get some formatting on retrieved columns in ORACLE 11G.

So far my query is as follow:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT MOVIETITLE "MOVIE", TO_CHAR(ROUND(AVG(REVIEWSTAR),3),'99.00') "REVIEWSTAR",CRITICCLASSDESC
    FROM TBLMOVIE JOIN TBLREVIEW USING(MOVIEID) 
    JOIN TBLCRITIC USING(CRITICID) 
    JOIN TBLCRITICCLASS USING(CRITICCLASSID)
    GROUP BY MOVIETITLE,CRITICCLASSDESC
)
PIVOT
(
    AVG(REVIEWSTAR)
    FOR CRITICCLASSDESC IN('Critic' AS "CRYTIC RATING",'User' AS "USER RATING")
)
ORDER BY MOVIE;
```

and I am getting following output:

[image: OUTPUT]

and I want following output:

[image: Desired Output]

I mean the formatting of the columns which has trailing 0s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change output in the result (after pivot calculation)

```
SELECT 
MOVIE,  
TO_CHAR("CRYTIC RATING",'99.00'),
TO_CHAR("USER RATING",  '99.00') 
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT MOVIETITLE "MOVIE", ROUND(AVG(REVIEWSTAR),3)"REVIEWSTAR",CRITICCLASSDESC
    FROM TBLMOVIE JOIN TBLREVIEW USING(MOVIEID) 
    JOIN TBLCRITIC USING(CRITICID) 
    JOIN TBLCRITICCLASS USING(CRITICCLASSID)
    GROUP BY MOVIETITLE,CRITICCLASSDESC
)
PIVOT
(
    AVG(REVIEWSTAR)
    FOR CRITICCLASSDESC IN('Critic' AS "CRYTIC RATING",'User' AS "USER RATING")
)
ORDER BY MOVIE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MOVIETITLE "MOVIE", 
case when CRITICCLASSDESC = 'Critic' then TO_CHAR(ROUND(AVG(REVIEWSTAR),3),'99.00') end as "Critic Rating",
case when CRITICCLASSDESC = 'User' then TO_CHAR(ROUND(AVG(REVIEWSTAR),3),'99.00') end as "User Rating"
FROM TBLMOVIE JOIN TBLREVIEW USING(MOVIEID) 
JOIN TBLCRITIC USING(CRITICID) 
JOIN TBLCRITICCLASS USING(CRITICCLASSID)
ORDER BY MOVIE;
```

If you will always only have a `user rating` and a `critic rating`, this is a simple way to do it without using the `pivot`.

Comment: You forgot aboutn group by )